# Can we use formula fields in lookup filters or how do I implement lookup filter to match `D.A` to be equal to `C.B.A`?

Tags: lookup, relationships, lookup-filter, childrelationship

I am trying to introduce a lookup filter.

I have standard object `A`, standard object `D` which has lookup to `A` and custom object `B__c` which has lookup to `A` and custom object `C__c` which has lookup to `B__c` and custom object `E__c` which has both lookups to `C__c` and `D`.

Is this possible to introduce a lookup filter on object E__c relation to `D` to require `D__r.A` to be equal to `C__r.B__r.A__c` ?

I have tried to create a Formula(Text) field on both `E__c` and `C__c` to have value of `C__r.B__r.A__c` but looks like I can't use that field to match field value from `D__r.A` and also it doesn't allow me to select more than one relationship depth.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way or simply put, any administrative point-and-click way to require `D__r.A` to be equal to `C__r.B__r.A__c` ?

This has to be implemented in `Group Edition`, so I can't use Apex Triggers or advanced configuration options like process builders. Also I don't want to implement a manage package only for that to be installed in the subscriber organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_limitations.htm&type=5),

> Lookup filter criteria can’t reference these types of fields on the
> source object:
>
> Blockquote
>
> Autonumber
>
> Encrypted
>
> Formula
>
> Long text area
>
> Multi-select picklist
>
> Roll-up summary
>
> Text
>
> Text area
>
> URL

and [to this documentation link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm&type=5), it is possible to choose related fields that are one relationship away from the lookup object.

> Select a suggested field from the Field text box. You can only select
> fields on the current record, the lookup object, or the user record.
> You can also choose related fields that are one relationship away from
> the lookup object. Salesforce assists you by listing the available
> fields and relationships when you click the lookup icon or click
> inside the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will not be able to use lookup filter, you can apply this logic in a validation rule and block the users